# Guest VM not having internet access through firewall VM

Tags: firewall, virtualization

I'm doing the following network setup (first time with firewall) but it's not working, unsure where its going wrong.

I have a Fortigate VM firewall port 1 IP 192.168.132.5 on vmnet8(NAT) in VMWare, host vmnet8 IP is 192.168.132.1, guest VM IP is issued by DHCP from firewall (working).

I have a static route between firewall and host vmnet

The firewall VM and guest Vm can ping host vmnet8 interface but do not gain internet access.

I have created a policy to allow WAN on LAN IPs (guest VM).

Anything I'm missing.

Thank You

[image: Guest VM IP]

[image: WAN & LAN IP settings]

[image: Static Route between firewall port 1 and host vmnet8]

[image: Internet Policy]

[image: Host vmnet8 IP]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now resolved.

What happened was I was setting manual IP addresses of both the WAN port 1 and the static route gateway as IP address of laptop vmnet8 which is 192.168.132.1.

What I tried was let the DHCP assign the WAN port IP and also let the static route get the IP dynamically (this was an option in the static route only showing when I allow DHCP IP assignment to WAN port 1..

I saw that the dynamically assigned static route IP is 192.168.132.2 (my laptop vmnet8 IP is 192.168.132.1), now I'm just not understanding who is assigning this IP to the static route, if its the VMware DHCP then how or to what is it getting assigned to or is it just a thing between VMWare and Fortigate.

What I have noticed is that the DHCP IP of WAN is 192.168.132.152 and not 192.168.132.2 or 3 or 4 etc, I have tested this twice.

A tracert from the guest client VM

```
tracert 8.8.8.8

Tracing route to google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1   <1 ms   <1 ms   <1 ms 192.168.15.10
  2   <1 ms   <1 ms   <1 ms 192.168.132.2 >>> IP first assigned dynamically by fortigate, then I set the same IP manually and it works.
  3   22 ms   5 ms   6 ms 192.168.1.254
  4   6 ms   14 ms   14 ms 192.168.10.1
  5   26 ms   20 ms   21 ms 10.8.15.1
  6   *     22 ms   18 ms 89.19.65.170
  7   *     36 ms   25 ms 89.19.65.201
  8   37 ms   79 ms   16 ms 74.125.244.1
  9   15 ms   25 ms   17 ms 72.14.239.219
10   17 ms   20 ms   15 ms google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]

Trace complete.
```